# how to clone a project from gitlab's development branch to your computer using ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I want to clone a repo above gitlab in the develop branch similar to this link: https://git.xxx/than/web-chat/tree/develop and I use ubuntu terminal but I only clone the master branch repo. Its: https://git.xxx/than/web-chat. So how can I clone a repo in the dev branch? I look forward to your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch <url>
```

To clone a single branch